# Not get javascript value in angular model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to change my textbox value after click on a button using javascript and change ng-model value of angular js.

The Javascript code working fine and change the textbox value, but I also want to change my ng-model value according to the text box.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function tryi()
        {
             document.getElementById('newtry').value="any value";
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <label>Name:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" id="newtry">
      <input type="button" onclick="tryi();"value="click here">
      <hr>
      <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1><hr>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the sense behind doing this outside of the angular scope?

Comment: in other project i set one textbox value using javascript so that can not assign in ng-model so i have that type of problem.

Comment: You can also set the Textbox with JavaScript from within an Angular-Controller, then you wouldnt have this problem.

If you want to adjust a mode-value from OUTSIDE the angular-scope, you would need to use the `$apply()`-Method to notify angular about the changes. But i would recommend you read the Angular-Tutorial first (http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial), that explains how it works.

Comment: Read the docs before you ask these kind of questions.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have included **angular-resource** and  not included **angularjs**

add this line

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
```

the code is working fine

Here is the plunkr link: http://plnkr.co/edit/CPX1Mhn2CkmY6wZWHvya?p=preview